# multiple counts with sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, `gages` and `schedule`, and they are joined on their `company` and serial number (`gage_sn`).

I am attempting to get a total count for each month, for the next three months, and a total for the three months cumulatively like below:

```
type              this month     next month     two month from now     total
----              ----------     ----------     ------------------     -----
indicators            4              8                  2               14
calipers              0              16                 16              32
...
```

I currently have the following to get a total count of the gages, by type, that are due this month:

```
 SELECT G.GAGE_TYPE, COUNT(G.GAGE_TYPE)
   FROM GAGES AS G
        LEFT OUTER JOIN SCHEDGI AS S ON S.COMPANY = G.COMPANY AND S.GAGE_SN = G.GAGE_SN
  WHERE DATEPART(m, S.SCHED_DUE_DATE) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, +2, GETDATE()))
    AND DATEPART(yyyy, A.SCHED_DUE_DATE) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, +2, GETDATE()))
    AND S.SCHED_TYPE = 'CALIBRATION'
    AND G.COMPANY = 'ABC COMPANT'
    AND G.ISACTIVE = '1'
    AND G.EVENT_STATUS <> 'MSI'
    AND G.EVENT_STATUS <> 'AWREP'
    AND G.EVENT_STATUS <> 'LOST'
    AND G.EVENT_STATUS <> 'OOT'
    AND G.EVENT_STATUS <> 'CAL.'
    AND G.EVENT_STATUS <> 'REPAIR'
    AND G.EVENT_STATUS <> 'RETOOL'
    AND G.EVENT_STATUS <> 'SCRAP'
  GROUP BY G.GAGE_TYPE
  ORDER BY G.GAGE_TYPE
```

How do I modify my SQL to get the desired result?

Comment: Have you considered consolidating your `EVENT_STATUS` to using an `IN` clause?

Comment: Your sql doesnt seem correct.  Specifically the `GAGE_TYPE), (FROM`  I believe that to be a syntax error.  Could you verify that you've posted working sql?

Answer (score 1):

It's not particularly elegant, but short of doing a pivot, you could use some case statements and a sum.

Since `COUNT()` returns the number of rows in the `GROUP BY`, its only really useful for one grouping.

```
SELECT 
  GAGES.GAGE_TYPE, 
  SUM(CASE 
    WHEN (DATEPART(m, SCHEDGI.SCHED_DUE_DATE) = DATEPART(m, getdate())
         AND ( DATEPART(yyyy, SCHEDGI.SCHED_DUE_DATE) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, +2, getdate()))) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS 'ThisMonth',
  SUM(CASE 
    WHEN (DATEPART(m, SCHEDGI.SCHED_DUE_DATE) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, +1, getdate())))
         AND ( DATEPART(yyyy, SCHEDGI.SCHED_DUE_DATE) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, +2, getdate()))) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS 'OneMonths',
  SUM(CASE 
    WHEN (DATEPART(m, SCHEDGI.SCHED_DUE_DATE) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, +2, getdate())))
         AND ( DATEPART(yyyy, SCHEDGI.SCHED_DUE_DATE) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, +2, getdate()))) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS 'TwoMonths'
  --COUNT(GAGES.GAGE_TYPE)
FROM 
  GAGES GAGES 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  SCHEDGI SCHEDGI 
ON  
  (SCHEDGI.COMPANY = GAGES.COMPANY) AND (SCHEDGI.GAGE_SN = GAGES.GAGE_SN)
WHERE  
 ( SCHEDGI.SCHED_TYPE = 'CALIBRATION' )
  AND ( GAGES.COMPANY = 'ABC COMPANT' )
  AND ( GAGES.ISACTIVE = '1' )
  AND ( GAGES.EVENT_STATUS <> 'MSI')
  AND ( GAGES.EVENT_STATUS <> 'AWREP' )
  AND ( GAGES.EVENT_STATUS <> 'LOST' )
  AND ( GAGES.EVENT_STATUS <> 'OOT' )
  AND ( GAGES.EVENT_STATUS <> 'CAL.' )
  AND ( GAGES.EVENT_STATUS <> 'REPAIR' )
  AND ( GAGES.EVENT_STATUS <> 'RETOOL' )
  AND ( GAGES.EVENT_STATUS <> 'SCRAP' )
GROUP BY  
  GAGES.GAGE_TYPE
ORDER BY 
  GAGES.GAGE_TYPE
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to do something like this:

```
SELECT 
  GAGES.GAGE_TYPE, 
  sum(case when 
    SCHED_DUE_DATE >= 'XXX' and 
    SCHED_DUE_DATE < 'YYY' then 1 else 0 end) CurrMonth,
  sum(case when 
    SCHED_DUE_DATE >= 'YYY' and 
    SCHED_DUE_DATE < 'ZZZ' then 1 else 0 end) NextMonth,
  ...
    sum(1) as Total
```

And you'll need to replace the XXX and, YYY with the start date and end date of current month and ZZZ with the end date of next month, but you probably got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your table contains a column which tells about the month. Let that column be named 'month'.
You need to put this in your group by clause.

```
group by GAGES.GAGETYPE , month
```

Answer (score 0):

First, Thank you. your guildance helped greatly.

This is what I came up with after reading you posts:
SELECT 
  GAGES.GAGE_TYPE,

SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(m, SCHEDGI.SCHED_DUE_DATE) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, +0, getdate()))) AND ( DATEPART(yyyy, SCHEDGI.SCHED_DUE_DATE) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, +0, getdate()))) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'ThisMonth',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(m, SCHEDGI.SCHED_DUE_DATE) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, +1, getdate()))) AND ( DATEPART(yyyy, SCHEDGI.SCHED_DUE_DATE) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, +1, getdate()))) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'NextMonth',
 SUM(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(m, SCHEDGI.SCHED_DUE_DATE) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, +2, getdate()))) AND ( DATEPART(yyyy, SCHEDGI.SCHED_DUE_DATE) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, +2, getdate()))) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'TwoMonth',
 COUNT(GAGES.GAGE_TYPE)
FROM 
  GAGES GAGES 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  SCHEDGI SCHEDGI 
ON
  (SCHEDGI.COMPANY = GAGES.COMPANY) AND (SCHEDGI.GAGE_SN = GAGES.GAGE_SN)

WHERE
 ( SCHEDGI.SCHED_TYPE = 'CALIBRATION' )

```
   AND ( DATEPART(m, SCHEDGI.SCHED_DUE_DATE) >= DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, +0, getdate()))) AND ( DATEPART(yyyy, SCHEDGI.SCHED_DUE_DATE) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, +0, getdate())))
   AND ( DATEPART(m, SCHEDGI.SCHED_DUE_DATE) <= DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, +2, getdate()))) AND ( DATEPART(yyyy, SCHEDGI.SCHED_DUE_DATE) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, +2, getdate())))
```

AND ( GAGES.COMPANY = 'ABC COMPANY')

AND ( GAGES.ISACTIVE = '1' )

AND ( GAGES.EVENT_STATUS <> 'MSI')

AND ( GAGES.EVENT_STATUS <> 'AWREP' )

AND ( GAGES.EVENT_STATUS <> 'LOST' )

AND ( GAGES.EVENT_STATUS <> 'OOT' )

AND ( GAGES.EVENT_STATUS <> 'CAL.' )

AND ( GAGES.EVENT_STATUS <> 'REPAIR' )

AND ( GAGES.EVENT_STATUS <> 'RETOOL' )

AND ( GAGES.EVENT_STATUS <> 'SCRAP' )

GROUP BY
  GAGES.GAGE_TYPE

ORDER BY 
  GAGES.GAGE_TYPE

it works exactly the way I need it two.